# How to add downloadable product in bundle items magento

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable

I want to add downloadable products into bundle items.
For that I have changed/add downloadable tag in Mage_Bundle module in config.xml

-allowed_selection_types

simple

virtual

downloadable

allowed_selection_types

But it wasn't allow me to select products in bundle item selection. I am using magento 1.9.0.1
Can you please anyone assist for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add downloadable products to a bundled product you also need to set the option 'Links can be sold separately' to 'No' for the downloadable product.

Comment: I have set Links can be purchased separately to yes, but still it is not displaying into selections

Comment: Sorry, you have to set them to 'No' for this to work (updated my answer)

Comment: Yes, Its working, but after placing order it won't allow me to download. It is showing error "The link is not available".

Comment: Is the order invoiced?

Comment: I have not tested in order invoiced, yet i am checking from My account -> Downloadable product.

Comment: You can only download a product when the item is invoiced/payed for. If you invoice the order the download should work from the account menu

Comment: Hi, I doesn't get download link in Invoice email. Can please help me about this issue.

Comment: There is no download link in the email, it only works thru the my download option in de user account page. But the download is only available after the order is invoiced.

Comment: Hi I want to create bundle for downloable product in magento 2.3 do eveny have any solution for that.